# How to remove an trap event from logstash?

Tags: logstash

i have defined a lot of yaml for snmp trap that i want , and put these yaml in my mib directory(specificmibs),
and defined the mib directory in my conf as follows,
yamlmibdir => "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/snmp-1.2.0/data/ruby/snmp/specificmibs"

but how to remove the event when the mib can't found in yamlmibdir ?

How can I make logstash drop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many filters will add tags to the event if they don't function perfectly.  It doesn't look like the snmptrap input does this (but you should check your documents to make sure).

If not, you'd probably need to compare a good document to a bad document and look for a trigger among the fields that you get.  If the traps are coming from the same manufacturer, then you'd expect their mibs to have been translated and you could check for a missing field.

Comment: Can you give me more directions to do it